# Admob Native ads in Recyclerview andriod studio

Tags: android

I am facing this issue with my Recycler view while placing Admob ads after every 6 items

The problem is when the ads have been placed some of my items in the recycler view are not displayed. for example, if I have 13 items in my recycler view only 10 will be displayed and the remaining three items will be hidden.

I need help in solving how I can display all 13 items plus the ad without removing any item from the list.

This is the code i am using:

```
private  static  int VIEW_TYPE_CONTENT = 0;
private  static  int VIEW_TYPE_AD = 1;
private  static  int ITEM_FEED_COUNT = 6;

    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //inflate layout icare_item and native ad

    View view;
    if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_CONTENT){

        //inflate/return icare item
        view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);

    }
    else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_AD){
        //inflate/return native ad
        view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.native_ads, parent, false);
        return new HolderNativeAds(view);

    }else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

// for the onbindviewholder

```
 if (holder.getItemViewType() == VIEW_TYPE_CONTENT){

            int pos = position - Math.round(position  / ITEM_FEED_COUNT);}else if (holder.getItemViewType() == VIEW_TYPE_AD){
```

//display ads
}

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (mList.size() > 0 ){
        return mList.size() + Math.round(mList.size()  / ITEM_FEED_COUNT);
    }
    return mList.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if ((position + 1) % ITEM_FEED_COUNT == 0){
        //after five items show ad
        return VIEW_TYPE_AD;
    }else {
        //show content
        return VIEW_TYPE_CONTENT;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're saying you want an ad after every **five** items, right? So for ten items:

```
1 2 3 4 5 AD 6 7 8 9 10 AD
```

you'd expect 12 items total in the list. But this is how you're calculating `getItemCount`

```
mList.size() + Math.round(mList.size()  / ITEM_FEED_COUNT)
```

Ignoring the `Math.round` (which isn't doing anything here, you're using integer division i.e. truncating the result) you're calculating the number of ads by dividing the number of items by `ITEM_FEED_COUNT`. That should be the number of items it takes to show an ad, *5*.

Your result should be *10 + (10 / 5)* or *10 + 2*. But you have `ITEM_FEED_COUNT` set to **6**. For ten items in the list, that gives you *10 + 1* (because *10 / 6* is *1.667* which gets truncated to *1*). So in that case, the `RecyclerView` is only going to display *11* items

---

You're already using `ITEM_FEED_COUNT` for other calculations where it needs to be *6*, so either subtract *1* here, or (I personally think this is better) add a new variable like `ITEMS_PER_AD` set to *5*, and define `ITEM_FEED_COUNT` (or whatever you want to call it) as `ITEMS_PER_AD + 1`. They're directly related values, but you use them in different situations, depending on whether you're grouping the items up or your grouping items plus ads - I think it's clearer to have two separate properties there. Up to you though!

And I don't know why you'd have *10* items displayed if you have *13* in your list, nothing in your code would produce that combination, but see if it works for you if you change that item count calculation

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can you please express it in codes